# Mutliplying dataframe values by another dataframe and returning 'sumproduct' of columns for all rows

Tags: python, pandas

How do I summarise this data into one table using Pandas? 
I have two existing tables..

df1.., *Cost table*

```
> Month   A    B   C
> Jan    10    5   4 
> Feb     5   10   5
> Mar    20   10   8 
> Apr    10   10  10
> May     5   20  10
```

df2...  *Weighting Option*

```
>        A     B     C
> Option
> x     1.00  0.90  0.80
> y     0.95  0.75  0.60
> x     0.90  0.85  0.65
```

I want a new dataframe (d3) showing the totals for columns A+B+C when weighted by each of the options (x,y,z). It would look like this...

df3..,  *total cost in each month by weighting option*

```
>        x    y    z   
> month
>  Jan
>  Feb       
>  Mar       
>  Apr
>  May
```

E.g.. (Mar,y) above would be (0.95*20)+(0.75*10)+(0.60*8) = 31.3 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want a standard matrix multiplication, which can be done using `np.dot()`

```
pd.DataFrame(df1.values.dot(df2.T.values), columns=list('xyz'), index=df1.index)

          x      y      z
Month                    
Jan    17.7  15.65  15.85
Feb    18.0  15.25  16.25
Mar    35.4  31.30  31.70
Apr    27.0  23.00  24.00
May    31.0  25.75  28.00
```

### Edit:

As suggested by @Mr.F,

```
pd.DataFrame(np.dot(df1, df2.T), columns=list('xyz'), index=df1.index)
```

Comment: You can also just use `np.dot` directly on `DataFrame` arguments (which also support `.T` for transposition), such as: `pd.DataFrame(np.dot(df1, df2.T), columns=list('xyz'), index=df1.index)`